# How to fill form with same class but had different input name

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello So I want to fill the form this is the html of the website

```
<div class="vx_form-control" data-label-content="Address line 1">
  <div class="vx_form-control">
    <input type="text" aria-describedby="country_code_prefix AccountData_addressSuggest_helptext" aria-invalid="true" aria-autocomplete="none" aria-controls="suggestions" aria-activedescendant="0_suggestion" value="" autocomplete="off" name="/AccountData/address/address1" id="AccountData_addressSuggest" style="padding-left: 15px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried with this one to run on console Chrome

```
var xxx = document.querySelectorAll('.vx_form-control input[name="/AccountData/address/address1"]')
document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'My address');
```

But it doesn't work. Am I wrong on select the specific name?

Comment: You can use that selector without the `.vx_form-control` class of its containing parent if that name is unique. Otherwise you need to use it like `.some_class > input[name="some_name"]`

Comment: It seems they just fill the FOCUS class. I mean i clicked on some another class, they fill on that class. Not on the name i want to. It confusing

Comment: var xxx = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="/paypalAccountData/address/address1"]')
document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'Address 1');

Try this code and they just fill another class with focus mouse, or selected mouse click

Answer (score 0):

Below snippet shows selector working.

Is there a reason you need to use execCommand? It's considered depricated these days and a bit more complex.

```js
let cool_input = document.querySelector('.vx_form-control > [name="/AccountData/address/address1"]');
cool_input.value = "some address";
```

```html
<div class="vx_form-control" data-label-content="Address line 1">
  <div class="vx_form-control">
    <input type="text" aria-describedby="country_code_prefix AccountData_addressSuggest_helptext" aria-invalid="true" aria-autocomplete="none" aria-controls="suggestions" aria-activedescendant="0_suggestion" value="" autocomplete="off" name="/AccountData/address/address1" id="AccountData_addressSuggest" style="padding-left: 15px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens if you console.log the result of the querySelector?